# How to check if two strings are equal "regardless of one character"?

Tags: c++

I want to check if two strings are equal regardless of one character is missing. For example "HappyMan" equals "HappyMn" and "HappyMann" and "HappyMnn". Is there any built in function to do this task? I've tried to sort both of them then count how many characters are different but it doesn't work. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            cnt++;
        if (cnt > 1) {
            cout << "Not equal";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "Equal";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: "How do I do X - here's some code" isn't an acceptable stack overflow question.   You need to provide exactly what doesn't work with your code.

Comment: Supposedly your algorithm is wrong: a lot of strings become equal after sorting, so your algorithm cannot do what you've described. Here's one which should work: find the first non-matching character, and then skip it in the string which is longer. Then the remaining part must match.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
  std::string str1 = "manatee";
  std::string str2 = "mannatee";

  std::string strLong = "";
  std::string strShort = "";

  if (str1.length() >= str2.length()){
      strLong = str1;
      strShort = str2;
  }
  else{
      strLong = str2;
      strShort = str1;
  }

  if (strLong.length() - strShort.length() > 1){
      printf("%s", "They are not equal.");
      return false;
  }

  bool firstDifference = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < strShort.length(); i++){
    if (strShort[i] != strLong[i] && firstDifference){
        if (strLong.length() > strShort.length()){
            strLong = strLong.substr(0, i) + strLong.substr(i+1, strLong.length() - i 
            - 1);
        }
        firstDifference = false;
        continue;
    }
    else if (strShort[i] != strLong[i] && !firstDifference) {
        printf("%s", "They are not equal");
        return false;
    }    
  }

  printf("%s", "They are equal");
  return true;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    unordered_map<char, bool> umap;
    int cnt = 0;
    string longestStr = "";
    string shortestStr = "";
    if(a.size() > b.size()) {
        longestStr = a;
        shortestStr = b;
    }
    else {
        longestStr = b;
        shortestStr = a;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < longestStr.size(); i++)
       umap[longestStr[i]] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i<shortestStr.size();i++) {
        if (umap[shortestStr[i]] == false) {
            cnt++;
        }
        if(cnt > 1){
            cout << "Not Equal";
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "Equal";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fixed it, I hadn't understood your question but now it should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
  std::string str1 = "iceman";
  std::string str2 = "icemannn";

  std::string strLong = "";
  std::string strShort = "";

  if (str1.length() >= str2.length()){
      strLong = str1;
      strShort = str2;
  }
  else{
      strLong = str2;
      strShort = str1;
  }

  if (strLong.length() - strShort.length() > 1){
      printf("%s", "They are not equal.");
      return false;
  }

  bool firstDifference = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < strShort.length(); i++){
    if (strShort[i] != strLong[i] && firstDifference){
        printf("%s %i", "first difference found at ", i);
        strLong = strLong.substr(0, i) + strLong.substr(i+1, strLong.length() - i - 
1);
        firstDifference = false;
        continue;
    }
    else if (strShort[i] != strLong[i] && !firstDifference) {
        printf("%s", "They are not equal");
        return false;
    }    
  }

  printf("%s", "They are equal");
  return true;

}
```